# Vivado Simulator copy multiple values

Tags: simulation, system-verilog, vivado

I'm simulating a SystemVerilog based core on Vivado 2019.1. I can copy the value of any signal simply by select+right click+Copy Value, but when I select multiple signals (for my case I need to select about 15000 signals belonging to the same array), Vivado disables the Copy Value option.

Is there any way to select and copy multiple values from wcfg window?
If not, is there any way to save the values that the signals included in the wcfg window take at a specific time of simulation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see that the post is pretty old, but I stumbled upon the same issue and wanted to give some advice for the future. You can print all the values into the tcl command window by using executing the following command:

```
get_property value [get_objects /top/U0/signal]
```

if you want to influence the radix you can set the respective property

```
set_property radix dec [get_objects /top/U0/signal]
```

Allowed values are: default, dec, bin, oct, hex, unsigned, ascii, smag
More details in [UG835 - Vivado Design Suite Tcl Command Reference Guide](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2019_2/ug835-vivado-tcl-commands.pdf)